# How to disable and Enable the NVIDIA GPU from command line?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, gpu

I am using the OS Ubuntu "18.04.5 LTS (Bionic Beaver)" on an HP machine with NVIDIA graphics card. My applications can run both with and without GPU. I want to test and compare the results on the same box with and without GPU. So I want to run the test on the box once with GPU and once run the same test again by disabling the GPU and compare the results.

So, I want to understand how can I disable the GPU from command prompt and after the completion of the test again enable the GPU.

Please help me with the steps/commands.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this command to switch between intel or Nvidia GPU

```
sudo prime-select nvidia
sudo prime-select intel
```

You need to reboot for the change to apply

Make sure that Nvidia driver is already installed correctly. The easiest way to install it is go to Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers

Comment: Thanks ffauzan for the response. I tried the same and I see that profile is set to intel. root@ubuntu:~# sudo prime-select intel
Info: the intel profile is already set                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                              
But, when I check the resource utilization by the nvidia GPU, it still uses the resources.

Comment: # nvidia-smi
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|   0  Tesla P4            Off  | 00000000:14:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   37C    P0    23W /  75W |   5980MiB /  7611MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |